# How to make Categories with sub categories not linkable

Tags: magento

Should be a simple question. But i've got a category list in Magento that has sub categories. And i want to make my categories with subs under then act as a title, instead of a clickable link to that category. So for instance:

```
Link 1
Link 2
Link 3 (this should be a title)
---Link 1
---Link 2
Link4
```

I'm getting my categories likes so.

```
<?php foreach ($helper->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>


<li> <a href="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setData($_category->getData())->getUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $_category->getName() ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>

<?php foreach (Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())->getChildrenCategories() as $childCategory):?>
  <?php echo '<li class="subCats"><a href="'.$childCategory->getUrl().'">'.$childCategory->getName() .'</a></li>'; ?>
  <?php endforeach;?>

</li>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK this is a bit of a hacky solution, but it worked for me. Firstly create a local copy of:

**app > code > core > Mage > Catalog > Block > Navigation.php**

Or if you know how to configure modules, extend the class and do it the proper way.

Look for the function called **_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml**.

Somewhere on the page create yourself an array of all the category names you want to exclude:

```
$categoryArray = array("Duplicate NCR", "Triplicate NCR", "Quadruplicate NCR");
```

Now just surround the  tags with a standard if statement by replacing this:

```
$html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.' title="'.$this->htmlEscape($category->getName()).'">';
$html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
$html[] = '</a>';</code>
```

With this:

```
 if(!in_array($this->htmlEscape($category->getName()), $categoryArray)) {   

    $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.' title="'.$this->htmlEscape($category->getName()).'">';

    }

    $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';

    if(!in_array($this->htmlEscape($category->getName()), $categoryArray)) {    

    $html[] = '</a>';

    }
```

As I said, making a module of this would be the much better option, but in terms of a quick fix this will work perfectly.

Comment: This wouldn't be hacky if you renamed the block and edited the layout xml ;) It's the price we pay for Magento deciding to build the HTML inside a block. /me sighs